# Undefined reference to '_imp__*'

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw

I have an executable A, that I'm building using a static library B (which I have built before hand), both compiled with mingw32 (i686) 7.3 . A's build gives me a build error related to undefined symbols, which should be defined by setupAPI. Below are the error codes:

```
D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a(list_ports_win.cc.obj):list_ports_win.cc:(.text+0x17a): undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetClassDevsA@16'
D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a(list_ports_win.cc.obj):list_ports_win.cc:(.text+0x1a9): undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo@12'
D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a(list_ports_win.cc.obj):list_ports_win.cc:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiOpenDevRegKey@24'
D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a(list_ports_win.cc.obj):list_ports_win.cc:(.text+0x2de): undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA@28'
D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a(list_ports_win.cc.obj):list_ports_win.cc:(.text+0x34c): undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA@28'
D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a(list_ports_win.cc.obj):list_ports_win.cc:(.text+0x4c4): undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList@4'
```

CMake is used to build both of these projects. I've tried including setupapi in both projects, using

```
target_link_libraries(PROJECT setupapi)
```

and using the whole archive flag provided by CMake in projet B's compilation.

Note that the static library is known to work with a GUI we build using QT, so I suspect it is a CMake config issue. As it stands now, the code to include setupAPI, which is uniquely in project B's CMake file, is the following:

```
if(WIN32)
    message("Win32 detected")
    target_link_libraries(PROJECT_B setupapi)
    set_target_properties(PROJECT_B_STATIC PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/WHOLEARCHIVE")
    target_link_libraries(PROJECT_B_STATIC setupapi)
endif()
```

I'm wondering if it could be some step Qt does implicitly, as I can't see any major differences between our .pro file and project A's CMake file.

### Edit:

**Verbose mode dump**

```
-- Build files have been written to: D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/acpac_cscripts/build
[1/10] C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-7~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\C__~1.EXE   -I../. -I../../fx_plan_stack/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flexseastack -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flex_lib -I../../fx_plan_stack/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/serial/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-comm/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/CycleTester/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/DpEb42/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/i2t/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/utilities/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/logger/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-system/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/ActPack/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/Rigid/inc  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/findpolesexample.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\main.dir\findpolesexample.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/findpolesexample.cpp.obj -c ../findpolesexample.cpp
[2/10] C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-7~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\C__~1.EXE   -I../. -I../../fx_plan_stack/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flexseastack -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flex_lib -I../../fx_plan_stack/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/serial/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-comm/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/CycleTester/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/DpEb42/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/i2t/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/utilities/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/logger/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-system/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/ActPack/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/Rigid/inc  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/hold_position_example.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\main.dir\hold_position_example.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/hold_position_example.cpp.obj -c ../hold_position_example.cpp
[3/10] C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-7~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\C__~1.EXE   -I../. -I../../fx_plan_stack/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flexseastack -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flex_lib -I../../fx_plan_stack/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/serial/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-comm/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/CycleTester/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/DpEb42/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/i2t/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/utilities/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/logger/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-system/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/ActPack/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/Rigid/inc  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/two_dev_position_example.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\main.dir\two_dev_position_example.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/two_dev_position_example.cpp.obj -c ../two_dev_position_example.cpp
[4/10] C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-7~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\C__~1.EXE   -I../. -I../../fx_plan_stack/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flexseastack -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flex_lib -I../../fx_plan_stack/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/serial/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-comm/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/CycleTester/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/DpEb42/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/i2t/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/utilities/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/logger/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-system/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/ActPack/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/Rigid/inc  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/cppFlexSEA.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\main.dir\cppFlexSEA.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/cppFlexSEA.cpp.obj -c ../cppFlexSEA.cpp
[5/10] C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-7~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\C__~1.EXE   -I../. -I../../fx_plan_stack/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flexseastack -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flex_lib -I../../fx_plan_stack/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/serial/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-comm/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/CycleTester/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/DpEb42/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/i2t/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/utilities/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/logger/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-system/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/ActPack/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/Rigid/inc  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/read_all_example.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\main.dir\read_all_example.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/read_all_example.cpp.obj -c ../read_all_example.cpp
[6/10] C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-7~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\C__~1.EXE   -I../. -I../../fx_plan_stack/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flexseastack -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flex_lib -I../../fx_plan_stack/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/serial/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-comm/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/CycleTester/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/DpEb42/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/i2t/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/utilities/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/logger/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-system/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/ActPack/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/Rigid/inc  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/open_speed_example.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\main.dir\open_speed_example.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/open_speed_example.cpp.obj -c ../open_speed_example.cpp
[7/10] C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-7~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\C__~1.EXE   -I../. -I../../fx_plan_stack/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flexseastack -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flex_lib -I../../fx_plan_stack/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/serial/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-comm/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/CycleTester/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/DpEb42/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/i2t/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/utilities/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/logger/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-system/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/ActPack/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/Rigid/inc  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/leaderfollower.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\main.dir\leaderfollower.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/leaderfollower.cpp.obj -c ../leaderfollower.cpp
[8/10] C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-7~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\C__~1.EXE   -I../. -I../../fx_plan_stack/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flexseastack -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flex_lib -I../../fx_plan_stack/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/serial/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-comm/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/CycleTester/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/DpEb42/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/i2t/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/utilities/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/logger/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-system/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/ActPack/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/Rigid/inc  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/current_control.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\main.dir\current_control.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/current_control.cpp.obj -c ../current_control.cpp
[9/10] C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-7~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\C__~1.EXE   -I../. -I../../fx_plan_stack/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flexseastack -I../../fx_plan_stack/include/flex_lib -I../../fx_plan_stack/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/serial/include -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-comm/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/CycleTester/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/DpEb42/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-dephy/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/unity -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/i2t/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/utilities/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-shared/logger/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-system/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/ActPack/inc -I../../fx_plan_stack/flexsea-projects/Rigid/inc  -MD -MT CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF CMakeFiles\main.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.obj -c ../main.cpp
[10/10] cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-7~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\C__~1.EXE    CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/cppFlexSEA.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/read_all_example.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/open_speed_example.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/current_control.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/hold_position_example.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/findpolesexample.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/two_dev_position_example.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/leaderfollower.cpp.obj  -o main.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libmain.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
FAILED: main.exe
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~2\MINGW-~1\I686-7~1.0-P\mingw32\bin\C__~1.EXE    CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/cppFlexSEA.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/read_all_example.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/open_speed_example.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/current_control.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/hold_position_example.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/findpolesexample.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/two_dev_position_example.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/main.dir/leaderfollower.cpp.obj  -o main.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libmain.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a(list_ports_win.cc.obj):list_ports_win.cc:(.text+0x17a): undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetClassDevsA@16'
D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a(list_ports_win.cc.obj):list_ports_win.cc:(.text+0x1a9): undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo@12'
D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a(list_ports_win.cc.obj):list_ports_win.cc:(.text+0x1f1): undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiOpenDevRegKey@24'
D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a(list_ports_win.cc.obj):list_ports_win.cc:(.text+0x2de): undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA@28'
D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a(list_ports_win.cc.obj):list_ports_win.cc:(.text+0x34c): undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyA@28'
D:/Repos/Actuator-Package/fx_plan_stack/build/libs/libfx_plan_stack_static.a(list_ports_win.cc.obj):list_ports_win.cc:(.text+0x4c4): undefined reference to `_imp__SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList@4'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
/d/Repos/Actuator-Package/acpac_cscripts
```

Comment: in your CMakeList, what output does find_library gives you ? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_library.html

Comment: If the application is in a separate CMake project it won't know about the transitive link properties of archive B unless you define them or import them.  Archive B won't contain anything of the setupapi library either.  You need to check that the main application is correctly trying to link against setupapi.  For example using `make VERBOSE=1 my_target` will show the linking steps.

Comment: @Martin It appears to get setupapi from: C:/Windows/System32/setupapi.dll. Is that normal or should it be getting it from Mingw?

Comment: @Fred I've added the verbose dump (It's Ninja rather than Make) above. I'm not sure how to interpret the results as far as the linker goes. Could you give me some insight or point to a resource?

Comment: @Fred To address the second point in your comment, if I build them both in Project's CMake file, would I avoid this problem? If not is there a better way conserve the transitive link properties of B?

Comment: `setupapi` should be coming from MinGW; the DLL is the runtime file, not what the compiler links against build time.  Also the link line appears to be missing '-lsetupapi'.  So what ever is in your CMakeLists.txt file for the executable appears to be incorrect.  https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/ and https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html give an overview of executables and libraries.  If both the executable and library were in the same build then you wouldn't have to worry about export and importing usage requirements.

Comment: Since you've said that the executable has the command `target_link_libraries(my_target Setupapi)` and it's not working something else is going wrong.  This is all I had to do to use those particular functions in a test project using MinGW  (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) / Ninja on Windows 7.  I also think it's odd that your installation is showing DOS short-names on the command line instead of the regular file-names.